# Use static class by interface?

Tags: c#, class, interface, static

imagine you have some methods you need to access from your whole application. A static class is ideal for this.

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do Something here...
    }
}
```

But maybe in future I'll add a second implementation of the static methods in another static class.

```
public static class MyStaticClass2
{
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        // Do Something here...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change static class used in my other code without changing the calls from `MyStaticClass.MeMethod();` to `MyStaticClass2.MyMethod();`?

I thought about an interface but i have no idea how to implement this... If I'm talking crazy say it and I'll simply change the calls :D

Comment: No, there are no interfaces on static level. You can comment out the `MyStaticClass.MeMethod`'s body, and forward calls to `MyStaticClass2` if you're in a hurry ;)

Comment: You can put MyMethod() in another static class, that way you can access it from both of your current static classes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

so your factory is

```
public static class MyStaticClassFactory
{
   public static IMyNonStaticClassBase GetNonStaticClass()
   {
      return new MyNonStaticClass1();    
   }
  
}
```

Instance

```
public class MyNonStaticClass1 : IMyNonStaticClassBase
{
    //
}
```

Interface

```
public interface IMyNonStaticClassBase
{
   void MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: You can also use a DI container (depending on the complexity of your application).

Comment: I don't know much about DI, but I think that would be too complex for me :D

Answer (score 1):

We use (Windsor Castle) https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Windsor as factory Container.

It's the same principal.

You can have many implementations per individual Interface, but only one is ever associated to the interface in the Factory at run-time.

All you need to do is swap the implementation class at the Factory Level when you need to.

This is a really useful tool if your looking to optimize your code, i.e an Implementation class, as you have the safety of knowing that if you find any bugs in your new implementation class, you can simple swap out the implementation for the pre-existing one.