# Interface vs instance of class

Tags: c#, interface

My application has a BusinessLogic layer which calls out to a DatabaseAccessLayer,   which contains a static class for CRUD operations.  It opens a connection to my database, performs the update then returns (it doesn't store anything individually).

The problem comes when my endpoint needs to control the database that its writing to (TEST1, TEST2, DEV, etc).  I need to pass in a connection string into the static class.

I am struggling to understand why an interface is better than using a direct instance of a class or vice versa, or indeed if there is another preferred method (I read a post about using delegates but this seems old fashioned to me).

I have tried writing an interface, implement it in the DatabaseAccessLayer but how do I call that from my business logic layer?  I don't care what the code is in the DAL at the BL point, I just want it to call that code.  But it seems if I implement it, I have to implement all the methods (what code goes in there!).  And I understand that you can't declare an instance of the Interface and call the methods.

Can anybody suggest an approach?  Is using an instance of a class sufficient?

Comment: Using instance directly without interface is a subject of [technical debt](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/136002/156546). Not sure if word *static* is a key in your question, but see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19141977/1997232).

Answer (score 1):

I think you mix two rather distinct things, the Interface and the Instance of a Class.

In very simple words:

- An interface is like a **contract** - All the classes that will
  implement it **must** implement its methods
- An instance is like ...
  an ***Instance*** of a ***Class*** - i.e. an ***object*** made
  according to a ***blueprint***

Regarding your problem with various connections, now, this is another, I believe irrelevant problem. Your class is **static**, OK, that means you **may not create an instance** of it. You use it directly by calling its methods. You can always pass a connection string as a parameter to any of its methods. In fact that is what I suggest as a solution to your question:

*pass a connection string as a parameter to any of its methods*

Edit: Now that I see your question again... you might have faced problems with the Static Class member fields, IF you have the connection string as a field of your Static Class! Beware that fields of static classes are *shared*, meaning that, if changed by ANY of the endpoints using the class, they are changed for ALL the rest endpoints that will use the class. So, that might have caused you troubles...

In that case... again...
*pass a connection string as a parameter to any of its methods*

Edit2: No, that was wrong of me to suggest that you pass a conn String as a param to Data Layer!!! Data layer should have the connection string encapsulated (as an internal parameter). The consumers should not know the direction of the Data - whether it is DEV or PROD.

Comment: In WCF (which i am using in this solution) I have an interface, a client proxy (which makes a request down a channel) and an implementation of the code.  So what I was thinking is I could have an interface in the BL, code implemented in the DAL and then the BL just makes a request down the "channel" to the implemented code.  I am not sure i want to have parameters in each static method just because its repeating and not really necessary.  For the record i have no shared fields in my static class its very simple and dumb.

Comment: My problem here is that in my business i deploy endpoints which call down the WCF ultimately my requests update an ERP system database (of which we have several).  I may be testing one endpoint handling requests from a webstore to create orders to another doing something else - but on different controlled ERP instances.  I am only allowed one test server to host my WCF services on, so thought i could make the endpoint tell the WCF service which direction to go.  Currently i have the connection string in the WCF header... looks like i will have to use an instance with a constructor...

Comment: Generally you could do that! You could make your class non-static and add it a Constructor in which you will provide the direction of the data with a parameter. This way, the consumers will initialize the Instance of this class by calling the constructor with the suitable param value.